# "Does stats show" or "Do the stats show"

Tags: grammaticality

using Google show both sentences have been used. Which one is more correct?

a more detailed example:

- Does stats show who read my mail
- Do the stats show who read my mail

Comment: Google does not show that, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @snailplane try this for 1st one https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22does+stats+show%22&oq=%22does+stats+show%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6818j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&qscrl=1 and this for 2nd https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22does+stats+show%22&oq=%22does+stats+show%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6818j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&qscrl=1#q=%22do+the+stats+show%22&qscrl=1&safe=off

Comment: I think the problem is "stat" is probably not a real word. (At least I couldn't find it in some dictionaries.) Typically, "stat" is shorten from either "statistic" or "statistics", and that might cause some issues. However, I think it's safer to say "These stats show ..." or "Do these stats show ...?"

Comment: Use Google Ngram instead: [`do the statistics show,do these statistics show,do those statistics show`](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+the+statistics+show%2C+do+these+statistics+show%2C+do+those+statistics+show&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20the%20statistics%20show%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdo%20these%20statistics%20show%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 5):

### Simple Do vs Does Corrections

Stats is a short colloquial form of the word statistics. It is the plural version, withe the singular version being simply stat. In this type of question use does if you will use a singular or do with a plural.

> Does the stat show who read my mail?
>   Do the stats show who read my mail?

These are both correct and depend on what you are talking about.

### Using The vs These

As Damkerng T. mentions using "these" instead of "the" can make the sentence more clear.

> Do these stats show who read my mail?

This sentence is better if you are talking about a specific set of statistics. For example: if you are pointing to a Google Analytics page and were asking your systems administrator about what the statistics mean.